# Should I sanitize the output, which I seeded myself in the database of my rails web-app?

Tags: security, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am a web developer with very basic information in security. I have to take care of performance as well when each page is loaded. 
I am building a web-app using ruby on rails framework. 
I understand that the data we display on the web page should be sanitized.
There is some significant amount of data that we seed in our database by ourselves and it is displayed on our webpage. 
I am thinking should I sanitize that data or will it be an overkill to sanitize that data. Unless a hacker becomes admin or through some other way he changes our seeded data in the database directly, there is a rare chance that data will be changed.

I need some more security perspective to make this decision, should I sanitize it or not?

Comment: what kind of sanitization do you mean?

Comment: using rails sanitize method, which remove tags like: script, which may lead to alert pop up as soon as the page is loaded.

Comment: what if _you_ will need to add script tag to page content?

Comment: I will not sanitize that particular data which need html tags. But I am aware  that there is lots of data, which doesn't need to have those tags. Also, I am adding that data in the database, so I know the content.

Comment: as soon as only you is authorized to change the data - do not sanitize it, this will give you more flexibility. in case of hacker break into your database - doesn't matter whether you sanitized or not, he will still corrupt the content of your website and there are very many ways to work around any sanitization

Comment: What you are saying is correct, but your statement is quite broad. If a hacker tweaks only some data and I sanitize that while displaying can help my website from embarrassment and meanwhile we may take some countermeasures. PS: I have very less knowledge and need a better perspective.

Comment: you cannot sanitize everything (this is why sanitation is usually useless), and hacker can abuse your site with _any_ html tag, or even without tags at all, just post vulgar text or ASCII art picture